# Insert and link picture does not work in powerpoint mac

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-powerpoint-2016

The article https://www.indezine.com/products/powerpoint/learn/picturesandvisuals/2016-mac/insert-or-link-picture.html describes how to insert and link a picture in a powerpoint presentation. This way, if the picture file is changed, the picture in the powerpoint is also updated.

I followed the steps outlined, but the picture in the powerpoint does not update even after changing the picture file. I tried restarting powerpoint, but still nothing. Any one else experienced this issue or knows how to get the picture to update dynamically?

Comment: Does it update the image when you close PowerPoint then reopen it?

Comment: Unfortunately no, it does not.

Comment: What is the file extension of the image you are linking to?

Comment: pdf. I created the image using illustrator.

Comment: Aha! Interesting...

Answer (score 1):

## If possible, don't export your image as a PDF!

- Instead, export to another image format, such as PNG or JPEG.
- PowerPoint for Mac cannot dynamically update linked PDF images.

This limitation has existed since at least as far back as [PowerPoint 2011](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/1c98c005-b973-4497-b30c-9c1486b7fe8c/linked-pictures-not-updating-upon-original-image-change-in-powerpoint-2011-for-mac):

[image]

[image]